# How to find documents in MongoDB where field is a substring of an input string?

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I am working on a Node.js application with MongoDB as the database, and I have a collection named nevek_ferfi. Each document in this collection has a name property, and I want to find all documents where the name property contains a specific substring.

For example, suppose I have a document with name: "János Kukoda". If the keyword I'm searching for is "János," I want this document to be included in the search results.

Here's the code snippet I tried:

```js
async function findDocumentsWithSubstring(db, keyword) {
  try {
    const regexPattern = new RegExp(keyword, "i"); // Create a case-insensitive regular expression

    const result = await db.collection("nevek_ferfi").find({
      name: { $regex: regexPattern },
    }).toArray();

    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error occurred:", error);
  }
}
```

However, it seems that the regex pattern new RegExp(keyword, "i") is not correctly matching documents with the name property containing the substring.

Could someone please assist me in creating the appropriate regex pattern or suggest an alternative approach to find documents where the name property contains the specific substring?

In Vapor / Swift I implemented like this:

```
let cf = try await NevekFerfi.query(on: req.db).filter(\.$name ~~ ncs).count()
```